# My text from csv file is being read as raw string. It contains "it\'s" instead of it's. How do I clean this?

Tags: python, regex, nlp, sentiment-analysis, rawstring

**Sentence**:

```
'I understood that that morning did not work out for her but I would still like to to make an appointment with her. I mean if she does great lashes and it\'s just this one little hiccup in the beginning it\'s well worth it as far as I\'m concerned.'
```

How do I remove escape characters to clean the data?

Comment: Does your string also contain double quotes? Because if a string contains both single and double quotes, Python will need to escape on of them in the string's `repr` (and it chooses to do the single quotes).

Comment: No, actually it had double and single quotes but I cleaned it to make it single quotes.

Comment: Are you certain the data actually contains the backslashes? Depending on how you're processing and displaying the data, it may be the display code that is adding the backslashes for the purpose of display. A [mcve] would go a long way to answering that.

Comment: When I enter list[index] to fetch the sentence I still see the backslash. I have to tokenize the words in the sentence so I don't want the backslashes.

Comment: If we put that string literally into a python variable (eg: `s='I understand...I\'m concerned.'`, the backslash will _not_ be in the data. You can verify that by getting the length of the string and manually counting the characters. That is why we need an actual [mcve] and not just an approximation of your data. I recommend you start with a really short example string, for example, simply `I'm`. That way it will be obvious if your string has two bytes or three.

Comment: @BryanOakley Thanks a lot. This did work. I could tokenize my words as I wanted. Thank you!

Comment: Share your code and your data! See: [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

I guess, a simple `re.sub` might work:

#### Test

```
import re

string = '''
I understood that that morning did not work out for her but I would still like to to make an appointment with her. I mean if she does great lashes and it\'s just this one little hiccup in the beginning it\'s well worth it as far as I\'m concerned.
'''

expression = r'\\'

print(re.sub(expression, '', string))
```

#### Output

> I understood that that morning did not work out for her but I would
>   still like to to make an appointment with her. I mean if she does
>   great lashes and it's just this one little hiccup in the beginning
>   it's well worth it as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: I actually don't want to print it. So when I save each sentence as a list within a list,it still looks the same without any change.

Answer (score 0):

The right answer is in the comment from @bryan-oakley : there is nothing to be done.

As a test:

```
s = 'I understood that that morning did not work out for her but I would still like to to make an appointment with her. I mean if she does great lashes and it\'s just this one little hiccup in the beginning it\'s well worth it as far as I\'m concerned.'

assert len(s) == len(s.replace('\'', "'")) # passes
assert s == s.replace('\'', "'") # passes
```